# Convergence of $X_{n} = (-2)^{n}X$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Suppose we have X ~ N(0,1). $X_{n} = (-2)^{n}X, \forall n $

I'm trying to determine whether $X_{n}$ converges as $n \to \infty$ in either probability, distribution, almost surely or in $L^{p}$.

My intuition says that it does not converge in any of these forms because it oscillates infinitely between $-cX$ and $cX$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The weakest form of convergence among these is convergence in distribution. Since the cumulative distribution function of $X$ is continuous, we readily have for each $t$, $\mathbb P\{X_{2j}\leqslant t\}\to 1/2$ and $\mathbb P\{X_{2j+1}\leqslant t\}\to 1/2$. If the sequence $\left(X_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ was converging in distribution to $Y$, 
then we should have $\mathbb P\{X_{n}\leqslant t\}\gt 3/4$ for $n$ large enough, where $t$ is a continuity point of the cumulative distribution function of $Y$ such that $\mathbb P\{Y\leqslant t\}\gt 7/8$.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what you're arguing here. What if we had $(-1)^{2}X$ instead?

Comment: You mean $(-1)^nX$ I guess. In this case this has the same distribution as $X$, hence we have the convergence in distribution, but not in probability.

Comment: sorry yes, that is what I meant to type. How would I show that this has convergence in distribution?

Comment: $-X$ has the same distribution as $X$, hence $(-1)^nX$ has the same distribution as $X$ for each $n$.

Comment: I agree that each X has the same distribution as every X since $X$ ~ $N(0,1)$. But $X_{n} = (-1)^{n}X$ which I would think oscillates between -X and X as $n \to \infty$ no?

Comment: It is trivial that $X$ has the same distribution as $X$. What I meant is that $\color{red}{-}X$ has the same distribution as $X$.

Comment: Gotcha. And that's because of symmetry of the normal distribution right?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$